# Add multiple rows between drag and drop of table rows between two similar table in jquery with draggable and droppable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i am trying to drag a table row and to drop it in the similar table i.e, of same table structure. i am trying to implement with j query drag-gable and angularjs i found many example with single item drag and drop.[Single drag and drop with angularjs](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/btford/angular-dragon-drop/blob/master/example.html). But i need multiple selection like this [link](http://docs.webix.com/samples/15_datatable/22_dnd/01_basic_dnd.html).Any one have idea about this.

Comment: if you didn't found any, you will have to write you own directive ;)
share your code if you need help or you are done.

Comment: @nilsK need to know whether there is any directives...